# Create an array and arraypush

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a MySQL database where I retrieve an id and a web adress. All the webadresses have a simular structure: `www.aaa.com/main/sub/name`

I have a while loop that explodes the urls into `main`, `sub` and `name`, for each id I want to add the "id", "main", "sub" and "name" into an array, sort them, first on `main`, then `sub`, then `name`, so that I have:

```
Id Main   Sub          Name
1  Ford   Transit      blue
2  Ford   Transit      red
3  Subaru Impreza      green
4  Subaru whatever     blue
```

This is my code so far:

```
$total_array = array();
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $id = mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
    $adress = mysql_result($result,$i,"address");
    $temp = explode("/", $adress);
    $car = temp[3];
    $make= temp[4];
    $color = temp[5];
    array_push($total_array,"$id","$car","$make","$color");
    $i++;
}

/* SOME ARRAY SORTING */

print_r($total_array);
```

But I can't figure how to sort them, and I tried to get a name for each column, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: have you looked at the likes of usort?

Comment: In fact here is your answer http://www.php.net/array_multisort

Comment: But the first step is to name the column for let's say "car". If I try array_push($total_array, id => "$id", car => "$car); then I get an error

Comment: `mysql_*` api is deprecated use MySQLi  instead. Check this http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: Yes, because that is completely invalid, try something like `$total_array[] = ['id' => $id, 'car' => $car]`

Comment: Like this?array_push($prosedure_array,['id'=> $id ,'maincat' => $akuttemp[4], 'subcat => $akuttemp[5], 'name' => $akuttemp[6]]);

Comment: You can do that but my way also does the exact same thing since PHP is really good with arrays like that

Answer (score 0):

```
array_push($total_array, 
  array('id'=> $id, 'car'=>$car, 'make'=>$make, 'color' => $color));
```

is this what you want?